# Drupal frontend-specific language

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've installed and configured a Drupal project in English but the frontend of the site should be in dutch. Now i was wondering if it's possible to configure frontend specific translations. The error messages etc. of the website (in the frontend) should be in Dutch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your site with a single language, you need to install and enable it. Some parts of the translation might not be completed, so you might need to do some work yourself to get a 100% translated site.

If you want to run english or another language in the admin, [there is a module for that](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and probably best) way to do this is to select "Nederlands (Dutch)" as the default language during installation (there are detailed instructions on the install page on how to do this). Changing the default language after you've installed it (and with some content already added) might lead to problems (it's not recommended to do this)...

If you do decide to add "Nederlands (Dutch)" to your current Drupal install, make sure you first put the translation files in the correct place BEFORE activating the new language. You will also have to enable the Locale module BTW (if you haven't done so already).